# large image loading problem 

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I had tired loading an image form a url below is my sample code , when tried to load a large image which is greater than 8191 pixel in width or height the Event.COMPLETE is not dispatched , i am aware of the flash player 10 BitmapData limit ,so cant we load an image greater than this 8191 pixel limit ?is there any workaround for this  Or any other method you suggest in doing ?

```
 private function loadImage(url:String):void
                            {
                                var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);               
                                var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();              
                                var context:LoaderContext;
                                context = new LoaderContext();
                                context.checkPolicyFile = true; 
                                imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, image_completeHandler);      
                                imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

                                imageLoader.load(request,context);
                            }

            private function image_completeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                   trace(" Image load Complete");
            }

            private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void 
            {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
         }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you split up the images. If you need Flash to handle the images as one (moving, scaling) I would write a holder-class that adds the image pieces as children of the itself.

I added some code and a link to a test below. Look at the code in action [here](http://www.kazumakzak.com/code/tileimage/). (wait for the SWF to load).

//TestClass

```
package
{
    import com.kazumakzak.display.TileImage;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TestBigImage extends Sprite
    {

        [Embed(source="assets/piece.png")]
        private var imageClass : Class;

        private var _image : TileImage;
        private var _counter : Number = 0;

        public function TestBigImage()
        {
            // create image with tile size 640x480
            _image = new TileImage(640, 480);

            // add tiles at positions 
            _image.addTile(new imageClass(), 1, 1);
            _image.addTile(new imageClass(), 1, 2);
            _image.addTile(new imageClass(), 2, 1);
            _image.addTile(new imageClass(), 2, 2);
            _image.addTile(new imageClass(), 3, 1);
            _image.addTile(new imageClass(), 3, 2);

            // add to display list
            addChild(_image);


            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, render);
        }

        private function render(event : Event) : void
        {
            _counter += 0.05;
            _image.x = -640 + Math.cos(_counter) * 640
        }
    }
}
```

//TileImage.as

```
package com.kazumakzak.display
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TileImage extends Sprite
    {

        private var _tileWidth : int;
        private var _tileHeight : int;

        public function TileImage(tileWidth : int, tileHeight : Number)
        {
            _tileWidth = tileWidth;
            _tileHeight = tileHeight;
        }

        public function addTile(source : Bitmap, tileX : int, tileY : int) : void
        {
            source.x = (tileX-1) * _tileWidth;
            source.y = (tileY-1) * _tileHeight;

            addChild(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: splitting and merging is a sort of pain though.

Comment: Hi Mattias thanks for the reply , Dont we need the BitmapData to do the splitting ? i my case the image loading complete event is not dispatched to access the Bitmap . As u said i need this image to be manipulated in flash like applying some filter effects and saving the final image.

Comment: I think Mattias' point is that you should split the image already on the server and then load in the parts.

Comment: thanks grapefrukt for the reply , hope there is no other solution to do this in the client side .Will do the splitting in server. @ Mattias, it would be easier for me if u can post here the code for merging thanks .

Comment: I added some example code in my previous answer. Hope this could help you with your problem.